# How to run a .exe file asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, exe

I need to run a .EXE from a web browser using Asp.net, whenever particular button is clicked in a web page it should open up the installation wizard, rather than downloading it 
Can any one help me out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For obvious security reasons you cannot run EXEs on client computers from a web application. If this was possible that would be a huge security vulnerability. The best you could do is provide a download link to the executable and ask the client to download and install it.

If you on the other hand you want to run the executable on the server you could use the [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method.

Comment: yep ! thats a valuable info @darin thanks a lot  , but i have a small clarification , if u take up HP- QC when ever if v click on site administration link it installs certain files in OS , then hw is possible , it happens through web broswer

Comment: If the client uses Internet Explorer and explicitly authorizes ActiveX to be run this could be achieved. This could only work with Internet Explorer. For example on my machine I have disabled all ActiveX controls to be running and the HP-QC is not able to install anything.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run any exe you choose on a users machine. This would be huge security flaw.

You can consider [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) if you absolutely must use something like this

> ClickOnce is a Microsoft technology that enables the user to install
>   and run a Windows application by clicking a link in a web page.

Refer: [ClickOnce Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Browser support however is limited to IE and via addons on firefox.